# Zend Framework 2 - Best way to of catching and logging exceptions including within factories

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2

The following Zend Framework 2 code below creates an Elastic Search client. However if it can’t connect to elastic search because the service is unavailable an exception is thrown.

```
class ElasticClientFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return \Elasticsearch\Client
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new Client(
            $serviceLocator->get('Config')['elastic']['cluster']
        );
    }
}
```

My understanding is that to create a default error handler in Zend I should use the following.

```
$sharedManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', 'dispatch.error',
            function($event) use ($sm) {
            if ($event->getParam('exception')){
                $sm->get('Logger')->crit($event->getParam('exception'));
            }
        });
```

This code however only catches exceptions throw in controllers or during the dispatch process. Is there a way to catch exceptions thrown when creating a service using a factory. Its possible that this will happen quite a lot for example if a database goes down or any service the application is trying to connect to. I can't seem to find the correct way to catch exceptions which are thrown in a factory and have them handled by the global error handler above.

To solve this for now I have registered an exception handler on the logger which will log the exception thrown in the factory but this doesn't feel correct.

```
Logger::registerExceptionHandler($logger);
```

Comment: I think the best way is to try/catch exception in factory that way you can either choose to return false, or an empty client...Further more, Services are available during factory construction (you can access $serviceLocator), so you can register a Logger and use it to log your error without disturbing the MVC process stack. I just think it's smooth to handle factory error in factory process. Eventually error and exception when using the resulting instance will be handled after (like a failing request...etc), in controller for example.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I created a separate Zend Framework 2 module and did the following in the onBootstrap method

```
 public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $eventManager        = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $logger = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Logger');
```

catches exceptions for errors during dispatch

```
  $sharedManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', 'dispatch.error',
        function($event) use ($sm) {
        if ($event->getParam('exception')){
            $sm->get('Logger')->crit($event->getParam('exception'));
        }
    });
```

catches exceptions in application code that are uncaught. For example if a database server goes down.

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception) use ($sm, $event) {
            //ensure that the application log, logs a 500 error
            $event->getResponse()->setStatusCode(500);
            $extractor->setResponse($event->getResponse());
            http_response_code(500);
            $sm->get('Logger')->crit($exception);
    });
```

global catchall to log when a 400 or 500 error message is set on a response. This is mainly for logging purposes.

```
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH,
        function ($e) use ($logger) {
            $statusCode = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
            $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
            if($statusCode >= 500) {
                $e->getResponse()->setStatusCode($statusCode);
                $sm->get('Logger')->crit($e->getResponse());
            }
            if($statusCode >= 400 && $statusCode < 500) {
                $e->getResponse()->setStatusCode($statusCode);
                $sm->get('Logger')->err($e->getResponse());
            }

        }
    );
```